# Add custom view (tileview) to layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, setcontentview

I'm an Android Beginner and I would like to know how I can add a custom view to the layout `activity_main.xml`.

In my `MainActivity` I have the following:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);         

    }
```

And I want to add a `Tileview` to my `activity_main` layout:

```
 TileView tileView = new TileView( this );
  tileView.setSize( 2000, 3000 );  // the original size of the untiled image
  tileView.addDetailLevel( 1f, "tile-%d-%d.png");
  setContentView( tileView );
```

Both of them work good separately. While I can't create multiple `setContentView`, I would like to know how I can create the `tileView` into the `activity_main` layout (or to an id). I tried several things with `LayoutInflater` but without success yet.

Thanks in advance.

For `tileview` see: https://github.com/moagrius/TileView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add one of the `ViewGroup` subclass (E.g. `LinearLayout`) provided by the framework it to the `activity_main.xml` and assign it an id. It will act as container for your `TileView`. After you instantiate your `TileView`, retrieve this container with `findViewById` and call `addView` on it, providing as parameter the TileView you just instantiated and, optional, the `LayoutParams` for it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this?

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

TileView tileView = new TileView( this );
tileView.setSize( 2000, 3000 );  // the original size of the untiled image
tileView.addDetailLevel( 1f, "tile-%d-%d.png");

((RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rootView)).addView(tileView);
```

In case root view of your `activity_main` is a `RelativeLayout` with `android:id="@+id/rootView"`